# Delete features from FeatureCollection in GeoJSON?

Tags: geojson, features

I have a FeatureCollection in GeoJSON. I want to delete all features that have an ID that doesn't start with "B".

```
{
  "type": "FeatureCollection",
  "features": [
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "id": 0,
      "properties": {
        "map": "eu",
        "name": "Belgium" // don't delete
      },
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Polygon",
        "coordinates": ...
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "id": 2,
      "properties": {
        "map": "eu",
        "name": "CzechRepublic" // do delete this Feature
      },
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Polygon",
        "coordinates": [ ...
```

I can do this manually in Python, but is there a nicer way to do it, using something on the command line?

Comment: What do you mean by manually? Do you just need to convert your existing logic to a command line tool? If so, please provide your code.

Comment: I mean I can load the JSON object into Python, iterate over it and selectively delete features. But I thought perhaps there is a gdal tool that could do this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Theoretically you can do it with ogrinfo, SQLite SQL dialect and -sql parameter.

```
ogrinfo -dialect sqlite -sql "delete from OGRGeoJSON where name not like 'B%'" json.json
```

However, it does not work because for GDAL existing GeoJSON files are read-only. But try it with shapefile and you will see that it works.

```
ogrinfo -dialect sqlite -sql "delete from json where name not like 'B%'" json.shp
```

If you want to use some GDAL command line tool you must copy what you want to keep instead of deleting what you want to get rid of.

```
ogr2ogr -f geojson -dialect sqlite -sql "select * from OGRGeoJSON where name like 'B%'" selected_only.json json.json
```

Amazing, isn't it?